# How to tag methods as final in UML?

Tags: java, uml, final

How to tag methods as final in the Unified Modeling Language  ? What about fields and class ?

Have you an example of diagram ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a stereotype `<<final>>` and you're done.

Answer (score -1):

"final" is a keyword in Java, but not UML. Afaik there is no common way to denote a method (or anything else) as final.

UML is a very high level modeling language and therefore small language characteristic (low level) things are not included.